# Play mp3 in android studios project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3

I am some problem with reproduce an mp3 file in my android app

i dont know but the file isnt recognize

i attached the print screen

[image]

im trying to select archive but I get this error like printscreen

[image]

someone help me ? thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is obvious as stated, the filename should not have upper case letters use

```
vorriemanonpost.p3
```

as the name

Comment: @riccardoairone Glad to see it worked !! Can you please also upvote the answer. Helps with the reputation and score :)  !!